# In which file in the bitcoin source code is the signature verification process done?

Tags: digital-signature, bitcoin, ecdsa

I'm looking for the transaction signature verification process in the bitcoin source code (from https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) but I can't find it. Where is it done ?

Answer (score 1):

A bitcoin transaction does not have a signature. Instead, it references outputs from previous transactions by supplying an unlocking script for each of the referenced outputs.

For more information about the transaction layout see [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction)

The transaction verification code can be found in `tx_check.cpp` and `tx_verify.cpp` [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/src/consensus).

The actual `script` execution code can be found in `EvalScript` [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/script/interpreter.cpp)